# Using :not to remove formatting

Tags: html, css

I have a class `rightband`, which is inside of a `message` class. Sometimes, the parent `<div class="message">` has an id `subnote`, sometimes - not. The code is below:

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="rightband">
        <img id="img-up" src="arrow-up.png")" />
        <img id="img-down" src="arrow-down.png")" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="subnode" class="message">
    <div class="rightband">
        <img id="img-up" src="arrow-up.png")" />
        <img id="img-down" src="arrow-down.png")" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS, for particular reasons I need to have the child class `rightband` formatted to change on hover and not the parent class.

```
#img-up, #img-down {
    display: none;
}
#subnode .rightband:hover #img-up {
    display: block;
}
:not(#subnode) .rightband:hover #img-down {
    display: block;
}
```

On `.rightband:hover` I need to show the `#img-up` when there is an id="`subnode`" in the parent and show `#img-down` when the parent does not have the `subnode`.

Can this be done in CSS and how?

Comment: FYI: ID is supposed to be a unique attribute. You should change all instances of `img-up` and `img-down` to classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#img-up, #img-down {
    display: none; 
}
.rightband:hover #img-down {
    display: block;
}
.rightband:hover #img-up {
    display: none;
}

#subnode .rightband:hover #img-up {
    display: block;
}    
#subnode .rightband:hover #img-down {
    display: none;
}
```